# How to write SQL bigquery query to calculate quantity of customers for the first and last day of month?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

We have table `deals`, which contains organization_id, won_time.
If the last Deal with this client was won a >3 months ago, that is a lost client.
To calculate the number of customers at a certain moment, you need to calculate the number of Organizations that have Deals marked won <=2 months before the moment. For example, when calculating amount of existing clients for January, Google Inc. should have at least 1 won deal in December or November.
Also, I want to have column with new clients for this month.
I want to have table with such columns (start_quantity, end_quantity, new_clients, month)

I tried to write smth like this, but it doesn't work correctly

```
WITH date_array AS (
  SELECT DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(month, INTERVAL 2 MONTH), MONTH) AS first_day_of_month
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS month
)

SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT org_id.value) AS num_customers,
  date_array.first_day_of_month AS month
FROM
  `deals`
RIGHT JOIN date_array 
ON DATE_TRUNC(CAST(won_time AS DATE), MONTH) = date_array.first_day_of_month
WHERE 
  CAST(won_time AS DATE) <= DATE_SUB(date_array.first_day_of_month, INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

Comment: Hi - are you just considering months at month end rather than specific dates i.e. for Jan deals within 3 months cover Jan/Dev/Nov whereas if you were considering dates then on 15th Jan any deal > 15th Oct would be within 3 months?